# How to use Google dataflow python to do partitioned gs sink by field in data(parquet)

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to read data from GS bucket and output it to another GS bucket (partitioned by custom column, arrival_date) into another bucket. The data is in parquet format. Looking for Apache beam Python based source code to run in dataflow.

Source data has three columns: org, name, arrival_time
Expected output: org, name, arrival_time into folders org wise..

```
# Instantiate a pipeline with all the pipeline options
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)


#Processing and structure of pipeline 
p \
| 'Input: QueryTable' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(
    query=known_args.bql,
    use_standard_sql=True)) \
| 'Output: Export to Parquet' >> beam.io.parquetio.WriteToParquet(
        file_path_prefix=known_args.output,
        schema=parquet_schema,
      file_name_suffix='.parquet'
    )
```

I am looking for an answer on how do I implement writing to GS folders partitioned by custom column (org in this case)

Comment: Hi @P.T , if your question is related with the writing in GCS from BigQuery, you might want to take a look in to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data). There is an example with Python. Please keep in mind that there are a [few limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_limitations), but I consider that it should not affect you.

Comment: I am less familiar with Python SDK. I did a quick check and didn't see a clear API to achieve what you want. So instead, could you pre-partition your data by the column to different PCollection and write those into your distention folders?

Comment: Hi @BraulioBaron, Thanks for help. I am actually looking for dataflow/beam python implementation to write parquet in folders based on custom column..

Comment: Hi @RuiWang, Can you please share or point me to source code on pre-partition PCollection and writing to different folders.. I hope this arrangement will also be able to handle the large scale of the data that I am working with..

Comment: It can be done by this transform(I found one in Java): https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Partition.java. It just creates more PCollection from one and then you can write those PCollection into your bucket independently.

Comment: In addition to @Rui Wang, [here is an example with Python](https://medium.com/@brunoripa/apache-beam-a-python-example-5644ca4ed581), [here the Github Repo](https://github.com/brunoripa/beam-example). Here you can see [how to read/write in Buckets](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pipeline-io)

Comment: @P.T Hi, do you know how to use WriteToParquet for writing to GCS?